# configurine .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, opencart

I have an opencart site hosted under www.farmaciagimeno.com (in the root html path, no subfolder). I have tried everything, but it just won't work. My .htaccess file looks like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

# Prevent Directoy listing 
Options -Indexes

# Prevent Direct Access to files
<FilesMatch "\.tpl">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

#<FilesMatch "\.ini">
 #Order deny,allow
 #Deny from all
#</files>

# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule ^(.*)\?*$ index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php [L,QSA]
```

The page gives me the following error:  **HTTP 500 (Internal Server Error)**
Well, you can see it yourself at www.farmaciagimeno.com

Do you know what can be the problem?

thanx

Comment: check your error logs

Comment: Chcek You hosting provider if You are allowed to use `Options +FollowSymlinks` or `Options -Indexes` - some hosting providers do not support editing these options... Also, the last rule `RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php [L,QSA]` seems like bullshit to me... Why did You remove the original `RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]` ???

Comment: ok, but even if I delete the .htaccess file, it gives me an error...isn't that strange?

Comment: @Perroloco: Unless you read apache error log file you won't know what is causing this 500 error.

Comment: Go back to the point where it was working by undoing (reverting) all the last changes You have done... You should be able to find out what causes the error to happen, finally.

Comment: @shadyyx This site was in an other hosting before, so it never worked here!

Comment: If the error persists without the `.htaccess` file then the error is obviously unrelated to the `.htaccess`, thus you are asking the wrong question. You really need to check your error logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite of the downvotes, I will post what solved my problem:

It was the f.%&@ing encoding and line break conversion of the .htaccess file.

Setting the encoding to ANSI and line break conversion to UNIX, it started working.